# is there a way to setup timeout in grpc server side?

Tags: python-multithreading, grpc-python

Unable to timeout a grpc connection from server side. It is possible that client establishes a connection but kept on hold/sleep which is resulting in grpc server connection to hang. Is there a way at server side to disconnect the connection after a certain time or set the timeout?

We tried disconnecting the connection from client side but unable to do so from server side. In this link  [Problem with gRPC setup. Getting an intermittent RPC unavailable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52993259/problem-with-grpc-setup-getting-an-intermittent-rpc-unavailable-error), Angad says that it is possible but unable to define those parameters in python.

My code snippet:

```
def serve():
server = grpc.server(thread_pool=futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2), maximum_concurrent_rpcs=None, options=(('grpc.so_reuseport', 1),('grpc.GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_TIME_MS', 1000)))
stt_pb2_grpc.add_ListenerServicer_to_server(Listener(), server)
server.add_insecure_port("localhost:50051")
print("Server starting in port "+str(50051))
server.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(60 * 60 * 24)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.stop(0)
if __name__ == '__main__':
serve()
```

I expect the connection should be timed out from grpc server side too in python.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you may find `context.abort(...)` useful, see [API reference](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.ServicerContext.abort). Timeout a server handler is not supported by the underlying C-Core API of gRPC Python. So, you have to implement your own timeout mechanism in Python.

You can try out some solution from other StackOverflow questions.

Or use a simple-but-big-overhead extra threads to abort the connection after certain length of time. It might look like this:

```
_DEFAULT_TIME_LIMIT_S = 5

class FooServer(FooServicer):

  def RPCWithTimeLimit(self, request, context):
    rpc_ended = threading.Condition()
    work_finished = threading.Event()

    def wrapper(...):
      YOUR_ACTUAL_WORK(...)
      work_finished.set()
      rpc_ended.notify_all()

    def timer():
      time.sleep(_DEFAULT_TIME_LIMIT_S)
      rpc_ended.notify_all()

    work_thread = threading.Thread(target=wrapper, ...)
    work_thread.daemon = True
    work_thread.start()

    timer_thread = threading.Thread(target=timer)
    timer_thread.daemon = True
    timer_thread.start()

    rpc_ended.wait()
    if work_finished.is_set():
      return NORMAL_RESPONSE
    else:
      context.abort(grpc.StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, 'RPC Time Out!')
```